# Magento 2 - extension hello world template .phtml not executing

Tags: magento2, template, frontend

Ok - I am about to tear my hair out.  The issue is that the template for my test extension is not executing - or does not appear to be executing.

The page displays - the title shows up on the page - but none of the content actually ends up on the page.  When I insert some debug code into my block file I see it at the top of the page.  When I insert some debug code into the .phtml file - I do not see anything.

Here is what I have so far (The pertinent bits so far that is):
I have debugged down to the block code is executing, and the .phtml code is NOT executing or does not seem to be updating the content page that is pushed out.

> Kevin\Extension\view\frontend\layout\kevin_extension_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Page Title 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Kevin\Extension\Block\Main" name="success" template="Kevin_Extension::success.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body> </page>
```

> Kevin\Extension\view\frontend\templates\success.phtml

```
<h2>test</h2>
<p><?php echo $this->getSuccessContent();?></p>
<?php echo "here too";?>
```

> Kevin\Extension\Block\Main.php

```
<?php
namespace Kevin\Extension\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Main extends Template
{
public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
{
    $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    return parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
...
```

None of the content above shows up on the page.  However, the title "Page Title" **DOES** show up on the page - and if I change it in the .xml file - it does change on the site on the frontend.

*SIGH* - it's probably something very obvious - but I can't figure out what.

Here is a screen shot of the output.  As you can see the title is showing up.
The content that should be displaying from the .phtml file is not displaying.
[image]

Comment: did you extend the Block Kevin\Extension\Block\Main from Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template?

Comment: I updated my original question to include the main.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  This was an exercise in frustration!  I had everything correct - and when I copied my extension to another directory structure, renamed everything properly, the copied extension worked like a champ!

Several hours later - the only difference?  The non-working extension was installed to the app/code directory via a symlink - and the test copy was not a symlink.  The symlink directory was the "Extension" directory BTW - not the Kevin directory.

Apparently magento does not like symlinks when accessing phtml files - OR I have my server misconfigured in some way.

> **ANSWER:** the extension was installed with a symlink directory - which
>   broke access to the .phtml file - but not to other files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your block class `Kevin\Extension\Block\Main` extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` (or one of it's descendants)

For a sanity check, use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` as a block class and at least see if you phtml debug appears.

If you still have problems, could you post you post the content of `Kevin\Extension\Block\Main`

Comment: Updated to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

layout is not loading in your module so change your code ie. pass one more parameter $pageFactory.

 `public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }`

```
public function yourfunction()
{   //your code 
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}
```

Comment: it started working 100% once I remove the symlink for the extension and copied it fully into the app/code directory.